# Handle 'Could not get any response' in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to do AWS deployement of data using mongo DB ATlas. Now here, I am trying to achieve a solid error handling system here with logging facility. I have covered most of the error scenarios other than 'Could not get any response' error (this error comes up when my connection with mongoDB fails)

I am providing this handler in the end of my routing file `app.use(errorHandler);` while `next(new Error("Could not complete this request"));` in the end of my routing function.

```
const app = express();
const errorHandler = require('./../routes-error-handler/routesError');

exports.signupAUser = (req, res, next) => {

    const user = new User({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        role: req.body.role,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    user.save()
        .then(response => {
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'User created successfully'
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Failed to create user',
                error
            })
        });

    next(new Error("Could not complete this request"));
}
```

routesError.js:

```
exports.errorHandler = (error, req, res, next) => {
    fs.appendFile('log.txt', `Not Found! Timed out response! Please try at a later time ${error}`, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
    res.json({
        message: 'Not Found! err Timed out!',
    })
}
```

Please let me know a good way to achieve error handling for 'Could not get any response'

Comment: Why are you called `next(new Error())` **before** you have a response to your call to `user.save()`?

Comment: You should put ```next(new Error("Could not complete this request"))``` in ```catch``` of ```user.save```

Comment: @TienDuong i cannot do that, mongodb is down, so it will never go in catch block. Reason is clear, if it will try to save() user and then fails only then it should go in catch block, not when mongo client is down.